# How to click and follow errors in VSCode just like Visual-studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am very new to VSCode and a former Visual Studio user. Historically, when you click on a Visual-studio error, it does take you to the pice of code that actually contributed to that error. However, in VSCode, I can see what error is caused when I do dotnet build but there is no way to click and go to the error location.

I am just wondering if there is any way this can be done in VSCode?

Comment: Where are you looking at the error?

Comment: @RobLourens : In the terminal tab of Output window

Comment: If the path is formatted correctly, then you can ctrl+click to open the file

Comment: I tried both `CMD + click` and `ctrl+ click` but it seems like the message does not contain browsable location.

Comment: It needs to be an absolute path or a relative path from the cwd